# connect-modrewrite to rewrite url

Tags: node.js

I am running webrtc html on node.js port 8080 
I am trying to rewrite the url on node.js

I installed both modules connect-url-rewrite and connect-modrewrite

can you advice me with example and where can add the script on server.js or on html pages itself

Please advice

Answer (score 4):

You don't need both connect-url-rewrite and connect-modrewrite. Pick one of them and go with that.

I'd suggest reading up a little on how Connect middleware works.

Essentially, you create a Connect app, and call `use` on it, passing in the rewrite function with a set of rules. [There's a good example the Github page for connect-modrewrite.](https://github.com/tinganho/connect-modrewrite) I've reposted it here with some simplifications:

```
var app = connect()
app.use(modRewrite([
  '^/test$ /index.html',
  '^/test/\\d*$ /index.html [L]',
  '^/test/\\d*/\\d*$ /flag.html [L]'
]))
app.use(connect.static(PATH_TO_STATIC_FILES_DIR))
app.listen(3000)
```

If you don't know what the strings inside of the modRewrite call mean, you'll have to read up a little on rewrite rules. Essentially, the pattern is: `<regular expression for url fragment> <target> <optional flags>`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Where could one find documentation for these rewrite rules? Are they javascript regular expressions, or are they specific to connect-modrewrite?

Comment: Good question, Christopher. It's been a couple of years since I answered the question, so I'm not totally sure I know what I'm talking about, but they look like normal regex patterns to me.